# Dynamic Activity Chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two "viewer" activities that perform the same function, but one, the legacy viewer, has better support for older APIs.  The user can switch to the legacy viewer in settings in case they have issues.

There are two ways to open the viewer, either through the launcher which opens a gallery activity, or through a VIEW intent which goes directly to the appropriate viewer.

Since the viewer can be called directly from an external app there needs to be logic to decide which viewer to display.  I did so in the form of a "ViewerChooser" activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent viewer = new Intent();
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!settings.contains(FullSettingsActivity.KEY_UseLegacyViewer))
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(FullSettingsActivity.KEY_UseLegacyViewer, !Util.hasHoneycomb());
    }

    if(settings.getBoolean(FullSettingsActivity.KEY_UseLegacyViewer, false))
    {
        viewer.setClass(this, LegacyViewerActivity.class);
    }
    else
    {
        viewer.setClass(this, ImageViewerActivity.class);
    }

    viewer.setData(getIntent().getData());
    startActivityForResult(viewer, REQUEST_VIEWER);
}

/**
 * Simply forward on the result
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    setResult(resultCode, data);
    finish();
}
```

It also forwards the results back out if needed.  This is functional but a little clunky in that the activity will show a blank screen for a split second.

Is there a better way to accomplish handling the same intent with two different activities selected dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `onClick` method or whatever method you use to launch the activity:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}
```

Comment: Initially that's what I did, but it can handle intents.  For example a file browser requesting VIEW on an image will open the viewer directly so it needs to be a little more advanced than that, hence the intermediary ViewerChooser.

Comment: Write two different activities and call the one for the API needed. Or use this in the same intent (class) and whenever you do something condition it to the OS running. Really there isn't more I can tell you; you just have to find a smart way using this code to run your app accordingly to the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

You get the blank screen since you are using an Activity to decide which OTHER Activity to run.  Why not try registering a Broadcast Receiver for the VIEW intent and launch the appropriate Activity from there.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll be gone for the weekend, but I'll take a look at BroadcastReceivers when I get back and update you.  Thanks.

Comment: BroadcastReceivers are a pain with the new security.  Until the app is explicitly run they aren't registered.